# Does a pointer assigned a malloc'ed return value also need to be malloc'ed

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

**Overall Question:** When you assign a return value which has been allocated via `malloc` to a pointer, do you need to `malloc` that pointer as well, or can you simply declare and assign it?

So for example, let's say I have a function `foo`, which in the course of its execution creates a `char *` using `malloc` and assigns its value. The function then returns that `char *`. If in another function (`main` in the example) I want to set a different `char *` equal to the result of `foo`, do I have to `malloc` that new variable as well? Or can I skip the extra `malloc` call and have the value assigned in `foo` persist?

```
char* foo (char *someVal) {
    /* other code happens */

    char *result = malloc((strlen(someVal)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(result, someVal, strlen(someVal);
    result[strlen(someVal)] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s = "xxxx";

    // Version 1: doing malloc first:
    char *manip1 = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    manip1 = foo(s);

    //Version 2: skipping malloc and directly assigning:
    char *manip2 = foo(s);

    /* perform some operation on manip */
}
```

So looking at the example, could I have simply done *Version 2* from the above code, or do I have to do *Version 1*?

Comment: Version 1 creates a memory leak. Version 2 is correct.

Comment: The standard name for your `foo()` is [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) (formally standardized in POSIX, but not in the C standard).  In your `main()` (version 1), you have a major leak; the data from `malloc()` is lost completely.  No, you don't need to do a double `malloc()` like that.  Version 2 is correct.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. Just use `malloc(strlen(someVal)+1)`.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense that it's a memory leak. And the part of the sample code where I instantiate `result` was just supposed to be filler, but now I'm glad I included, as I didn't know about `strdup` before -- thanks for the tip @JonathanLeffler .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to (and should not) allocate space beforehand. A pointer is just that, a pointer. It can point to anything, including something it's not supposed to (i.e. unitialized pointers).

As an illustration: Suppose you point at a house. Do you have to own a house to point to someone else's? You can point wherever you want. In a similar way, you don't have to **own** memory before **pointing** at someone else's.

Of your examples, version 1 creates a memory leak, since you no longer have any way to reference the memory you allocated initially. Version 2 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Malloc it allocates memory for the variable. In your example the method foo will return a pointer to the newly allocated memory. With your Version 1 you are allocating memory which will be pointed to by manip1. You are then changing manip1 to point to the memory allocated in the foo funation, thus causing a memory leak.